# Timer doesn't stop after changing bool to false in IF statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this strange problem. When I call stopTimer(), it changes the bool, but UpdateTime is still working and timer is going. Everything works, but the timer doesnt stop.

```
    public float elapsedTime;
    public float startTime;

    public bool stopTimer = false;

    private bool keepTiming = true;
    
    void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(keepTiming)
        {
            UpdateTime();
            
        }else{Debug.Log("Timer has stopped");}

        if(stopTimer)
            Debug.Log(StopTimer());
    }

    public void UpdateTime()
    {
        elapsedTime = Time.time - startTime;
        float t = Time.time - startTime;

        string minutes = ((int) t/ 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
        
        timeText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        
    }

    float StopTimer()
    {
        keepTiming = false;
        return elapsedTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: General question: Do you manipulate the time scale at some point? Because if not -> You could simply use a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) instead

Comment: I try your code and it work just fine for me. Are you sure you don't call the UpdateTime method from another source ? You can check method reference on visual studio (right click and _Find all references)_

Comment: @derHugo If I change time scale, wont my methods stop working?

Comment: @D.B VS code says only 1 reference, from Update function

Comment: Time scalling is a unity thing and it won't modify the stopwatch. That is why derHugo told you to use StopWatch if you keep the Time scale to 1.
Can you check the reference to the keepTiming  property ?

Comment: @zalias what I mean is: `Time.time` is affected by the `Time.timeScale` so if you change it the time will run faster or slower. `StopWatch` uses the unscaled system time and is similar as if you would use `Time.unscaledTime` everywhere instad

Comment: You know btw that you are "stopping" the timer continuously **every frame** .. in general you should make your code event driven and not poll check a `bool` value in `Update`

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding static to keepTiming bool. I don't really understand why, but it worked.

Comment: If 'static' fixed the issue you encountered then the problem could be caused by having 2 instances of your class.